# Testing modal.open() using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

So this is my $scope function. I want to test this by Jasmine.

```
$scope.viewIndividualDetailsByTitle = function(details){
        $modal.open({
             templateUrl: 'components/content-management/content-assessment/partial/title_detail.html',
             controller: 'ContentAssessmentTitleDetailCtrl',
             size: 'lg',
             backdrop: 'static',
             resolve: {
             cpPortfolioTitle: function(){
                    return details;
             }
             }
        });

     };
```

This is what I wrote in Jasmine.

```
describe('Ctrl: ContentAssessmentCtrl', function(){
beforeEach(module('cmsApp'));
var ContentAssessmentCtrl, scope, modal, modalInstance, httpBackend, ContentAssessmentService, event, controller;

beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $modal, $httpBackend, _ContentAssessmentService_){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    modal = $modal;
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    ContentAssessmentService = _ContentAssessmentService_;

    ContentAssessmentCtrl = $controller('ContentAssessmentCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        ContentAssessmentService: ContentAssessmentService
    });

    modalServiceMock = {
        open: function(options) {
        }
    };

    httpBackend.whenGET('/mcw/api/content_provider_status_mapping/contentProviderStatus/3').respond();
    scope.$digest();
}));



it('should test viewIndividualDetailsByTitle', function(){
    var details = {
        contentProvider:{
            name:'Test'
        },
        title: 'Test',
        productionYear: 1,
        titleCategory:{
            name:'Test'
        },
        runningTime: 1,
        country:{
            name:'Test',
            code:'Test'
        }
    };
});

it('should show the modal', function(){
    spyOn(modal, 'open');
    expect(modal.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
});


});
```

But I always have an error "Expected spy to have been called. I'm new on Jasmine like this is my first time so please bear with me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've got all the boilerplate setup for the test, but you're not actually calling the function that opens the modal. After the line where you create the spy you can call:

```
$scope.viewIndividualDetailsByTitle();
```